# Delphi/pascal Parse a string to a combobox

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to parse a string (sys) that looks exactly like this

```
-1|low
0|normal
1|high
```

I need to pair them in a combo box, where for example, low is the caption and -1 will be the value. What is the best way to do this? What I have so far is:

```
 var
 sys : String;
 InputLine : TStringList;

   InputLine := TStringList.Create;
   InputLine.Delimiter := '|';
   InputLine.DelimitedText := sys;
   Combobox1.items.AddStrings(InputLine);
   FreeAndNil(InputLine)
```

This gives each line of the combo box as such:

```
 -1
 low
 0
 normal
 1
 high
```

Comment: put your stringlist into `for` and form your combo with odd/even values of index of a `for` loop

Comment: I don't see how you are struggling. You've already split the values. All you need to do is add them to the combo box.

Answer (score 3):

Parse it manually yourself.

```
var
  SL: TStringList;
  StrVal: string;
  IntVal: Integer;
  Line: string;
  DividerPos: Integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile('Whatever.txt');
    for Line in SL do
    begin
      DividerPos := Pos('|', Line);
      if DividerPos > 0 then
      begin
        StrVal := Copy(Line, DividerPos + 1, Length(Line));
        IntVal := StrToInt(Copy(Line, 1, DividerPos - 1));
        ComboBox1.Items.AddObject(StrVal, TObject(IntVal));
      end;
    end
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To retrieve the value from a selected item:

```
if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex <> -1) then
  SelVal := Integer(ComboBox1.Items.Objects[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]);
```